# java8 stream not showing the expected output

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Iterate the list and create multiple objects.
Below is the sample json:

```
"accountRequest": [
    {
        "accountId": "10EIIP",
        "custId": "11EE",
        "custName": "XYZ",
        "comments": null,
        "status": "active",
        "linkedDetails": [
            {
                "custCode": "001",
                "startOn": "2023-01-01",
                "loanType": "auto"
            },
            {
                "custCode": "002",
                "startOn": "2023-01-15",
                "loanType": "home"
            },
            {
                "custCode": "003",
                "startOn": "2023-02-10",
                "loanType": "home"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Account.java

```
    class Account{
    @JsonProperty("accountId")
    private Long accountId;
    @JsonProperty("custId")
    private String custId;
    //custName, comments, status
    private String custCode;
    private LocalDate startOn;
    private String loanType;
}
```

I need to create list of "Account" by storing each of linkedDetails. The sample code below does not store accountId, custId, custName, comments, status in the "Account" object. **Expected output is to create List of size 3..**

```
List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
List<AccountRequest> accountRequestList = request.getAccountRequest();
accountRequestList.get(0).getLinkedDetails().forEach(linkedDetails -> {
    Account account = new Account();
    //need to set accountId, custId, custName, comments, status in each account object
    account.setCustCode(linkedDetails.getCustCode());
    account.setStartOn(linkedDetails.getStartOn());
    account.setLoanType(linkedDetails.getLoanType());
    accountList.add(account);
});
```

Expected Output :

```
"accountList": [
    {
        "accountId": "10EIIP",
        "custId": "11EE",
        "custName": "XYZ",
        "comments": null,
        "status": "active",
        "custCode": "001",
        "startOn": "2023-01-01",
        "loanType": "auto"
    },
    {
        "accountId": "10EIIP",
        "custId": "11EE",
        "custName": "XYZ",
        "comments": null,
        "status": "active",
        "custCode": "002",
        "startOn": "2023-01-15",
        "loanType": "home"
    },
    {
        "accountId": "10EIIP",
        "custId": "11EE",
        "custName": "XYZ",
        "comments": null,
        "status": "active",
        "custCode": "003",
        "startOn": "2023-02-10",
        "loanType": "home"
    }
]
```

Comment: what output you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a mutable list and modifying it in a foreach you should directly collect to the `accountList`:

```java
        List<AccountRequest> accountRequestList = request.getAccountRequest();
        List<Account> accountList = accountRequestList.get(0).getLinkedDetails().stream().map(linkedDetails -> {
            Account account = new Account();
            //need to set accountId, custId, custName, comments, status in each account object
            account.setCustCode(linkedDetails.getCustCode());
            account.setStartOn(linkedDetails.getStartOn());
            account.setLoanType(linkedDetails.getLoanType());
            return account;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Please see the expected output i have added in the post above. I want to iterate the linkedDetails and create number of objects based on LinkedDetails size.